# Ubuntu Server 17 can't suspend with systemctl

Tags: suspend, radeon

I installed an Ubuntu Server 17 but it seems I can't put it in sleep/suspend mode. When I use `systemctl suspend` , HDD restarts several times, each time monitor blinks for a moment and multi-line message appears for a second and then original command line returns . the message is this:

```
dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x150 returns -38
PM: device 0000:04:00.0 failed to suspend async: error -38
PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
[drm:uvd_v1_0_ib_test [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: fenece wait timed out.
[drm:radeon_ib_ring_tests [radeon]] *ERROR* radeon: failed testing IB on ring 5 (-110).
pci_legacy_suspend(): hpsa_suspend+0x0/0x10 [hpsa] returns -38
dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x150 returns -38
```

By the way the HDD that restarts seems to be connected to a HP Array: P410

Comment: [Ubuntu 17.04 crossed EOL in January.](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2018-January/000227.html) Please [upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/q/91815/250300).

Comment: @Melebius I'm having a hard time understanding why ponsfrilus added the 17.04 tag to the question when there was no apparent reason to add it, so I have rollback-ed this question to the author's original unedited version.

Comment: of course i upgraded . this is what happens after the upgrade .

Comment: I confirmed it , it is the problem with the p410 . by removing it i can suspend the system . but the hardware itself has no problem (or at least i don't think it has) because i  worked with it in windows 7 and there was no problem there , so i think the problem must be something operating system-wise .